# change levels in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to switch levels, but I get this Traceback error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Recovery 1\Desktop\Comp sci performance task\compscipretask (1) (1).py", line 228, in <module>
    walls,endRect,wallRect,wall  = load_level(currentLevel)
  File "C:\Users\Recovery 1\Desktop\Comp sci performance task\compscipretask (1) (1).py", line 87, in load_level
    for row in levels[level]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am really stuck here, and this is the last component of my game so any help is appreciated. I'm also fairly new to pygame and python so my experience is very limited. Thanks in advance!

The code:

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
pygame.init()
screenSize = (800,600)
displayScreen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenSize),0)
pygame.display.set_caption("U1A2 Test")


WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)

displayScreen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.update()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps= 60 
game = False
menu = True
inst = False
jump= False
x = 53
y = 552


walls = []
dx = 0
dy = 0

currentLevel = 0
sprite= pygame.image.load('block sprite.png')

levels = [[

    "                         ",
    "                         ",
    "          D              ",
    "          D              ",
    "                         ",
    "                         ",
    "  WW                     ",    
    "                         ",
    "                         ",    
    "        WWWW             ",
    "                         ",
    "                         ",
    "                WWW      ",
    "                         ",
    "                         ",
    "          WWW            ",
    "   WWW                   ",
    "                         ",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ],

    [

    "                         ",
    "                         ",
    "                   D     ",
    "                   D     ",
    "                         ",
    "     WW                  ",
    "                         ",    
    "               WW        ",
    "                         ",    
    "   WWWW                  ",
    "                         ",
    "                         ",
    "                WWW      ",
    "                         ",
    "                         ",
    "          WWW            ",
    "   WWW                   ",
    "                         ",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ]]

def load_level(level):
    m = n = 0
    wall = (x, y)
    walls = []
    for row in levels[level]:
        for col in row:

            if col == "D":
                endRect = pygame.Rect(m, n, 32, 32)
                walls.append(endRect)
            if col == " ":
                jump = False 
            if col == "W":
                wallRect = pygame.Rect(m,n,32,32)
                walls.append(wallRect)
                jump = True
            m += 32
        n += 32
        m = 0
    return walls,endRect,wallRect,wall     

walls,endRect,wallRect,wall  = load_level(currentLevel)         
while menu:


        fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("Ariel", 72)
        textTitle = fontTitle.render("change this", True, (255,0,0))
        displayScreen.blit(textTitle,(35, 50))

        fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("Ariel", 52)
        textTitle = fontTitle.render("Press 1 to play", True, (255,0,0))
        displayScreen.blit(textTitle,(35, 100))

        fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("Ariel", 52)
        textTitle = fontTitle.render("Press 2 for instructions", True, (255,0,0))
        displayScreen.blit(textTitle,(35, 150))
        pygame.display.update()

        fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("Ariel", 52)
        textTitle = fontTitle.render("Press 3 to quit", True, (255,0,0))
        displayScreen.blit(textTitle,(35, 200))
        pygame.display.update()


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_1:
                    print "ds"
                    game = True
                    currentLevel = 1 




                elif event.key == pygame.K_2:
                    menu = False
                    inst = True
                    displayScreen.fill(WHITE)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_3:
                    menu = False

        while game:


            #pygame.draw.rect(displayScreen,GREEN,PlayerRect,0) 



            #pygame.draw.rect(displayScreen, (255, 0, 0), PlayerRect, 1)



            #walls, players = load_level(level1)
            clock.tick(fps)                                 
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type ==pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    sys.exit()

                elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        dx = -7
                        displayScreen.fill(WHITE)

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                        dx = 7
                        displayScreen.fill(WHITE)

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_w:    
                        dy = -25

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        dy = 25
                        displayScreen.fill(WHITE)

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        stop = True
                        displayScreen.fill(WHITE)

                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                            dx = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:    
                            dy = 0            

            oldx = x
            oldy = y                           
            x = x + dx
            y = y + dy

            if game == True:
                dy = dy + 2

            if (x>=798 or x<=2):
                x=oldx


            if (y<=3 or y>=597):
                y=oldy 

            displayScreen.fill(WHITE)

            for wall in walls:
                PlayerRect = pygame.Rect(x,y, sprite.get_width(), sprite.get_height())
                if PlayerRect.colliderect(wall):
                    if dx > 0:
                        PlayerRect.left = wall.right

                    if dx < 0:
                        PlayerRect.right = wall.left

                    if dy > 0:
                        PlayerRect.bottom = wall.top

                    if dy < 0:
                        PlayerRect.top = wall.bottom

                    dy = 0

            for wall in walls:
                pygame.draw.rect(displayScreen,BLUE,wall,0)
                pygame.draw.rect(displayScreen,RED, endRect, 0)

                if PlayerRect.colliderect(endRect):
                    currentLevel += 1
                    walls,endRect,wallRect,wall  = load_level(currentLevel)


            displayScreen.blit(sprite,(x,y))
            pygame.display.flip()


        while inst:
                fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("Ariel", 72)
                textTitle = fontTitle.render("Instructions", True, (255,0,0))
                displayScreen.blit(textTitle,(35, 50))

                fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("Ariel", 52)
                textTitle = fontTitle.render("- Use W to jump,S to fall", True, (255,0,0))
                displayScreen.blit(textTitle,(35, 100))

                fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("Ariel", 52)
                textTitle = fontTitle.render("- Control your jump by using the A and D keys", True, (255,0,0))
                displayScreen.blit(textTitle,(35,150))
                pygame.display.update()

                fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("Ariel", 52)
                textTitle = fontTitle.render("- Move left and right with the A and D keys", True, (255,0,0))
                displayScreen.blit(textTitle,(35, 200))
                pygame.display.update()

                fontTitle = pygame.font.SysFont("Ariel", 52)
                textTitle = fontTitle.render("Press 3 to exit", True, (255,0,0))
                displayScreen.blit(textTitle,(35, 250))
                pygame.display.update()

                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                        if event.key == pygame.K_3:
                            inst = False
                            displayScreen.fill(WHITE)
                            menu = True

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: It's difficult at best to help with problems like this without you providing enough code for us to reproduce the problem -- especially when you're using global variables like you are. Please read [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry last time a posted a question i was told the same thing, so I only put a small amount of code this time. I will edit it will the full code

Comment: We don't necessary need (or _want_ the full code). Just enough to cause the problem to happen.

Comment: OK, after digging up a random .png file to use as a stand in for your `'block sprite.png'` file, I can run your program. How do I make it call the `load_level()` function that's causing the `IndexError`?

Comment: walls,endRect,wallRect,wall  = load_level(currentLevel)

Comment: When I run the program that never happens, so I figured there must be some way to interact with it to cause the call to occur. Please tell us how to recreate the problem.

Comment: when you go to the red square on the first level, this problem occurs. Sorry i misinterpreted your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, as the error message indicates, that the index used with the `levels` list is out of range. It can only be `0` or `1`. The problem appears to be because in the main `while game` loop you increment `currentLevel` by one without checking its value before or after. Initially it was set to `0` but later it gets set to `1` when user presses the <kbd>1</kbd> key to play game.

```
            for wall in walls:
                pygame.draw.rect(displayScreen,BLUE,wall,0)
                pygame.draw.rect(displayScreen,RED, endRect, 0)

                if PlayerRect.colliderect(endRect):
                    currentLevel += 1  # unconditionally increments the value
                    walls,endRect,wallRect,wall = load_level(currentLevel)
```

I'm not sure, but setting its value to `1` when the user starts playing may be wrong. Regardless, you either need to add some checks to prevent it from ever getting out-of-range or always check it's value before use. One obvious way would be simply making incrementing it conditional:

```
            for wall in walls:
                pygame.draw.rect(displayScreen,BLUE,wall,0)
                pygame.draw.rect(displayScreen,RED, endRect, 0)

                if PlayerRect.colliderect(endRect):
                    if currentLevel < 1:  #### LIKE THIS ####
                        currentLevel += 1
                    walls,endRect,wallRect,wall = load_level(currentLevel)
```

Even better, you could make the program more flexible by avoiding hardcoding constants that might change in your code. Here that could be done by defining a global constant near the beginning:

```
HIGHEST_LEVEL = len(levels)-1  # index of topmost level
```

...and then using it any and every where necessary to ensure `currentLevel` is or stays valid:

```
                    ...
                if PlayerRect.colliderect(endRect)
                    if currentLevel < HIGHEST_LEVEL:
                        currentLevel += 1
                    ...
```

Using this approach here would allow you can add levels to the game and not need to search far and wide though the code making sure `currentLevel` was always in range — much as I had to do in the process of debugging your program.